# lua set an elseif statment to recognize letters from the alphabet

Tags: if-statement, lua

In lua how can I set an elseif statment to recognize letters from the alphabet from user input?
For instance: elseif age = (alphabet) then
print("Invalid age")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the [tonumber](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-tonumber) method to evaluate if the input is a number or not and modulo, the `%` operator, to test if the number is an integer.

For example if limited to editing only the `elseif` statement:

```
elseif not tonumber(age) or tonumber(age)%1 ~= 0 then print("Invalid age")
```

If you can make a function or edit the code to do it in similar way then this would be more efficient method since it calls tonumber less:

```
local function IsInteger(number)
    number = tonumber(number)
    return number and number%1 == 0
end

-- later in code
elseif not IsInteger(age) then print("Invalid age")
```

Comment: You call ```tonumber``` A LOT, may I suggest assigning ```tonumber(age)``` to a variable before the if statement? It'll be more efficient, and shorter.

Comment: Also I'm confused as to why you used math.floor instead of the % operator like in my answer. It eliminates an additional function call, and is faster anyway.

Comment: @warspyking The question was specificly for the elseif statement.
For any code where I am not limited to that only I would make it call tonumber only once and save it to a variable. However here I am working in an IF statement and that is not possible within it unless I make a function or assume I can code elsewhere around the IF statement. I went with flooring since it works. Sure % works also, but I happened to think about floor first. Guess Ill add that % operator in and make a function version as well to the answer.

Comment: Well you can leave an if statement, with a blank --code

Comment: @warspyking I dont see the point of converting my answer to be exactly like your answer. You want me to copy paste your code to my answer? :) They are essentially the same already anyways.

Comment: No, was just hoping for an explanation as to why this is better so I could learn from it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

While I like Roch's method, I'm providing a method I find simpler.

```
local n = tonumber(age)

if n and n%1==0 then
    --code
else
      print("Invalid age!")
end
```

First to tonumber's age, to determine it's corresponding number.

Then it checks if n is true (neither nil, nor false), and because tonumber returns nil if it's not a number, will evaluate if it's a number.

The `n%1==0` part simply makes sure it's an integer.

I believe this method is more efficient.